# Proper icon size for Kindle Fire HDX 8.9

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I tried my app which provides a launcher icon up to xxxhdpi. However on the Kindle Fire HDX, there is a big bar in the middle and my icon there looks blurry while the built in apps have sharp icons.

Does anybody know how to provide the proper icon for that bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sideloading your APK then it will use the small, default icon. Once you submit your APK to the store and provide the relevant metadata (including a [range of image sizes](https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx2REB57251WV7Y/Optimizing-Your-App-s-Visual-Assets)) when the user installs the app the correct asset will be utilized.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to see how your icon would look before submiting to store:

It's taken from */res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png.*